# Kubernetes pod restart alert via stackdriver

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver

I have a stackdriver log based metric tracking GKE pod restarts.

I'd like to alert via email if the number of alerts breaches a predefined threshold.

I'm unsure as what thresholds I need to set inroder to trigger the alert via stackdriver. I have three pods via deployed service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the Logs Viewer and create a filter:

As a resource you should choose `GKE Cluster Operations` and add a filter.

Filter might look like this:

```
resource.type="k8s_cluster"
resource.labels.cluster_name="<CLUSTER_NAME>"
resource.labels.location="<CLUSTR_LOCATION>"
jsonPayload.reason="Killing"
```

After that create a custom metric by clicking on `Create metric` button.

Then you can `Create alert from metric` by clicking on created metric in `Logs-based metrics`.

Then setting up a Configuration for triggers and conditions and threshold.

As for the correct Threshold, I would take the average amount of restarts from past time period and make it a bit more for alerting.

Answer (score 2):

GKE is already sending to Stackdriver a metric called: `container/restart_count`. You just need to create an alert policy as described on [Managing alerting policies](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-alerting-ui). As per the [official doc](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_kubernetes), this metric expose:

> Number of times the container has restarted. Sampled every 60 seconds.